# How to show tiff file on arcgis js 4.x map

Tags: fastapi, arcgis

I got ndvi image from sentinel hub as tiff and return this tiff with fastapi.
In frontend side i get file as blob with axios.
My question is that - how can i show this tiff blob file on arcgis js 4.x map .
Or are there any solution to get image from sentinel hub and show it on a map using sentinelhub python.

I can get image as png from sentinelhub but there is a black background of image. So try to use tiff file for this.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Solution for getting ndvi image (tiff,png) from sentinelhub (in -1 and 1 range) and use this image to show on arcgis js 4.x map